# how to disable contextmenu of devexpress themedwindow in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, window, devexpress

I’m trying to disable popped contextmenu of ThemedWindow of devexpress when I click titlebar using mouserightbutton.

I used below code and it works in 'Window', but 'ThemedWindow' isn't working:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
    HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
    hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == 0xa4)
    {
        handled = true;
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

If I want to do same thing in ThemedWindow, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in below url:

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t728500/themedwindow-doesn-t-have-the-allowsystemmenu-property